# Perform order by relationship field in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to create product filter with Eloquent.

I start like this

```
$query = Product::whereHas('variants')
        ->with('variants')
        ->with('reviews')

$query = $this->addOrderConstraints($request, $query);

$products = $query->paginate(20);
```

Where

```
private function addOrderConstraints($request, $query)
{
    $order = $request->input('sort');

    if ($order === 'new') {
        $query->orderBy('products.created_at', 'DESC');
    }

    if ($order === 'price') {
        $query->orderBy('variants.price', 'ASC');
    }

    return $query;
}
```

However, that doesn't work, cause Eloquent is performing this query like this (information from Laravel DebugBar)

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `products` where exists 
(select * from `variants` where `products`.`id` = `variants`.`product_id`)

select * from `products` where exists 
(select * from `variants` where `products`.`id` = `variants`.`product_id`)

select * from `variants` where `variants`.`product_id` in ('29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48')
```

And so on

So when I try to use sorting by price it just obvious error

```
Unknown column 'variants.price' in 'order clause' (SQL: select * from 
`products` where exists (select * from `variants` where `products`.`id` =
```

`variants`.`product_id`) order by `variants`.`price` asc limit 20 offset 0)

So is it possible to perform relationship ordering with Eloquent or not?

Comment: You could also try `$query->orderByRaw('variants.price asc');`.

Comment: It really doesn't change query, still the same

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This will sort the subquery. Not the "first query (*the product query*)".

Basically, your subquery will be:
`select * from variants where product_id in (....) order by price`, and that is not what you want, right?

```
<?php 
// ...

$order = $request->sort;

$products = Product::whereHas('variants')->with(['reviews',  'variants' => function($query) use ($order) {
  if ($order == 'price') {
    $query->orderBy('price');
  }
}])->paginate(20);
```

If you want to sort product +/or variant you need to use join.

```
$query = Product::select([
          'products.*',
          'variants.price',
          'variants.product_id'
        ])->join('variants', 'products.id', '=', 'variants.product_id');

if ($order == 'new') {
    $query->orderBy('products.created_at', 'DESC');
} else if ($order == 'price') {
    $query->orderBy('variants.price');
}

return $query->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Searching `laravel relationship order by`, no one mention that `orderBy` inside relation only order the `subQuery` not the `first Query`. thank you!

Answer (score 6):

If you want to sort product and variants, you don't need joins, because you won't have the related model loaded (like `$product->variants`), just all the fields of the variants table.

To sort models by **related** submodels, we can use [Eloquent - Subquery Ordering](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#subquery-ordering).

To order the whole model by a related model, *and **NOT** the related model itself*, we can do it like this:

```php
return Product::with('variants')->orderBy(
    Variants::select('price')
        // This can vary depending on the relationship
        ->whereColumn('variant_id', 'variants.id')
        ->orderBy('price')
        ->limit(1)
)->get();
```