# Laravel Eloquent whereHas Issue

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to use Laravel Eloquent whereHas on my last row of HasMany relation for finding last update status But this query get me all actions off order .
I see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48276324/laravel-get-last-row-using-wherehas) . I want to use where query on lastAction and this not work for me. thanks

My Order.php file

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Order extends Model
{
    protected $table = "orders";
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function action()
    {
         return $this->hasMany(OrderAction::class, 'order_id');
    }
}
```

My OrderController.php file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;


use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class OrderController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $items = Order::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
            if ( !empty($request->filter_status )) {
                $query->whereHas('action',function($query1) use ($request){
                    $query1->where('state_to',$request->filter_status);
                });
            }})->latest('id')->paginate(20);

        $items->appends($request->query());
        return view('order.index',compact('items'));
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to use a join if you want to order by relationships. Otherwise it will always order your orders by latest id. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48321076/perform-order-by-relationship-field-in-eloquent

Comment: explain what you want?

Comment: I want to filter orders by state_to field in last added row in orderAction table ,
because my order last status store there

Comment: $items = Order::when(isset($request->filter_status),function($query)use($request){
            $query->select('orders.*',
                DB::raw('(select state_to   from order_action  where orders.id = order_action.order_id   order by  id desc limit 1) as state_to '            )
            );
            $query->where('state_to',$request->filter_status);
        })->latest('id')->get();
this code return unknown column state_to

Answer (score 0):

Something like that should do it (you may need to adjust the code to fit your application):

```
$items = Order::when(isset($request->filter_status), function($query) use ($request) { 
   $orderActions = OrderAction::selectRaw('MAX(id), state_to')
       ->groupBy('order_id');

   $query->joinSub($orderActions, 'order_actions', function ($join) {
       $join->on('orders.id', '=', 'order_actions.order_id');
     }) 
     ->where('state_to', $request->filter_status);  
 })
 ->latest('id')
 ->paginate(20);
```

Reference:
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#joins - Subquery Joins

Comment: This code return error , i fix it with groupby() but there is no difference in result and It's still a problem

Comment: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'offtapp_api.select max(id), state_to from `order_action`' doesn't exist (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `orders` inner join `select MAX(id), state_to from ``order_action``` on `order_id` = `orders`.`id` where `state_to` = CANCELED)

Comment: Could you please try changing query->join to query->joinSub($rawQuery, ‘order_actions’, function($join){ $join->on('order_actions.order_id', 'orders.id'); })

Comment: Thank You  , I didn't find answer but I approached to it  ,
If i can select state_to of row of  max(id) and grouping that(for getting last one ) ,  i get answer